# Not able to save data in firebase from web app

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am trying to save the details of user in the firebase as he enters in the website for sign up request but the details are not saving.
Here is the html code:

```
 <input type="name" placeholder="Full Name..." id="name_field1" class="inp" />
                                 <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="email_field1" class="inp" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Desired Password..." id="password_field1" class="inp" />
<button onclick="save()">Request Sign In</button>
```

The corresponding javascript used is:

```
var name=document.getElementById("name_field1");
var email=document.getElementById("email_field1");
var pass=document.getElementById("password_field1");
function save(){

var firebaseRef=firebase.database().ref();
var nam=comm.value;
var em=email.value;
var pas=pass.value;
firebaseRef.push().set(nam);
firebaseRef.push().set(em);
firebaseRef.push().set(pas);

}
```

Comment: What does happen? Do you get any error message? A quick spot - you're using `comm.value` for `nam`. Shouldn't that be `name.value`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the error but still i am not able to store the data even after rectifying the error. Also I am not getting any error message.

Answer (score 0):

you need to push values:

```
firebaseRef.push(nam);
firebaseRef.push(em);
firebaseRef.push(pas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has an amazing [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) on their website. I bet you'd master it within weeks if you read an article everyday.

Initialize your DB first:

```
// Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();
```

Write the data:

```
database.ref('users/ashley').set({
    username: value1,
    email: value2,
    profile_picture : value3
});
```

Also. **Please don't save user passwords in the DB**

Answer (score 0):

Do not leave ref() empty.try these one:

```
var firebaseRef=firebase.database().ref('testKey/');
```